# RecyclerView perform click from a fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to click a row of RecyclerView programmatically

I tried - `recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(2).itemView.performClick()`

But it is giving

> null pointer exception

sometime. 
I tried to check with trial and error I saw in a RecyclerView which is having 5 row and if I pass value more than 1 it's start giving null pointer exception.

Comment: if you need it for testing, try `Espresso` library it has wonderful `onData` recyclerview methods

Comment: No it's not for testing

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue. Problem was the recyclerView was not ready when I am trying click event. So I have added some delay.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myRecyclerView.getChildAt(locationData - 1).performClick();
            myRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(locationData - 1);
        }
    }, 500);
```